# Is there a way of parsing a PHP script but not executing/running it?

Tags: script, php, parsing

I know that you can run `php -l filename.php` to run a syntax check on a file, but is there a way of parsing the file without actually executing it (ie without running any of the in-built PHP functions) as a double-check against calling undefined functions for example?

[This guy](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/174336-dry-run-php-script-shell.html) has the same question, except he wants things like `print` to still produce output which I'm not bothered about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an IDE with a PHP plugin? That would allow you syntax highlighting and intellisense/code completetion, along with varying degrees of parse/checking. It looks like there are at least two for Eclipse: [PHPEclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpeclipse/) and [PHP Dev Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) - and one for visual studio: [vs.php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) (paid).

Comment: Netbeans for PHP is actually also very good for this (no plugins required), I was just hoping for more of a command line/independent tool